# How can I programmatically make a UICollectionView fill a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to do something fairly simple, but I keep getting errors.

I have a UITableView with multiple sections. Each section has a header and one UITableViewCell. Within each cell is a UICollectionView. All of these views must be created programmatically (I can't use storyboard solutions).

The problem is when I try to size and position the UICollectionView. I would like the UICollectionView to fill the entire UITableViewCell, so at first I tried to size the UICollectionView in the UITableViewCell's init method using self.frame like so:

```
var collectionView: UICollectionView?
let collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout!

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {

        self.collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        self.collectionViewLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 1.0, left: 1.0, bottom: 1.0, right: 1.0)
        self.collectionViewLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical

        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        let frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
        self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: self.collectionViewLayout)

        self.collectionView?.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView?.delegate = self
}
```

However, I think that the UITableViewCell's frame is not set at this time (the init method call), and so the UICollectionView is sized improperly. Is that correct?

Next, I tried using layout anchors, like so:

```
collectionView?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

This gave me a layout constraint error and said 'UICollectionViewProject[63851:2306772] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.' I don't understand how thats possible. I only added one constraint, there is nothing in storyboard, what constraints could it possibly be breaking?

Somehow I need to make this UICollectionView the same size as the UITableViewCell and fit inside it perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you have added just 1 `constraint` - `bottomAnchor`. `Autolayout` doesn't work like that. Just add all the required `constraints` after adding `UICollectionView` as `subview` of `UITableViewCell`, i.e.

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
{
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    self.collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    self.collectionViewLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 1.0, left: 1.0, bottom: 1.0, right: 1.0)
    self.collectionViewLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical

    let frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
    self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: self.collectionViewLayout)
    self.collectionView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.addSubview(self.collectionView!)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        self.collectionView!.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
        self.collectionView!.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor),
        self.collectionView!.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor),
        self.collectionView!.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor),
        ])

    self.collectionView?.dataSource = self
    self.collectionView?.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: Thanks PGDev! A critical piece of code that was missing from my original code was the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false. Without that property set to false the constraints will not work.

Comment: Sure..Happy coding..:)

Answer (score 1):

The size you're setting for you collection view will be overridden based on autolayout (automatically translated from the collection view default autoresizing masks) so you need to set up the appropriate constraints.

If you want your collection view to fill up your whole cell, try adding the following code at the end of your `init` method:

```
collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
addSubview(collectionView)

let layoutAttributes: [NSLayoutAttribute] = [.top, .bottom, .leading, .trailing]
let constraints = layoutAttributes.map {
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: $0, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: collectionView, attribute: $0, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
}
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
```

Then, you will have to calculate the height of your collection view and tell your table view delegate in the method `tableView(_:, heightForRowAt:)`.

Comment: Ferschae, the missing piece was collectionView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false. When I added that bit of code, your suggestion works perfectly. Please update your answer to include that bit of code. Thanks.

Comment: Of course! The default autoresizing masks constraints were conflicting with these ones!